# Decryption failed while trying to decrypt in postgres

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, encryption

I used `aes_encrypt` function in `Pyspark` for encryption and `aes_decrypt` for decrypting the data.

The encrypted data is inserted in postgres.

Now I need to `decrypt` the data using the same key in postgresql.

I tried using :

```
select decrypt(decode('c4Z2lZ+nNXKsqlqT1V9BUoKfE6elZe12sMeMADWW4Vw=' ,
                      'base64'), '1HarryPotterAndTheSorcerersStone', 'aes');
```

It is showing error as:

```
ERROR:  decrypt error: Decryption failed
SQL state: 39000
```

How can I `decrypt` data in postgres that was encrypted using `AES` from `pyspark`?